# Text getting cut while creating PDF file using Apache PDF box 2.0.6

Tags: apache, pdfbox

Creating pdf file by reading a text file

[image: SampleTextRead2.txt]

---

**using apache pdfbox 2.0.6**. Text which is being read is not getting displayed and is getting cut.

[image: SamplePDF.pdf]

Below is the **sample program** which I am using:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        PDDocument doc = null;
        TextToPDF text2pdf = new TextToPDF();

        try {
            doc = text2pdf.createPDFFromText(new FileReader("C:/sampleTextRead2.txt"));

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            stripper.writeText(doc, writer);
            writer.close();
            doc.save("C:/SamplePDF.pdf");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you somehow create a PDF from a text file and then extract the text from that PDF file again and you in some way are not content with the extracted text? If that is the case **A** share a sample text file and the PDF generated from it by the TextToPDF tool you are using to allow reproducing your issue.

Comment: You could call `setLandscape(true)` and you'll have more space.

Comment: hi @mkl, here in the above java code I am trying to read a text file named sampleTextRead2.txt through TextToPDF and then creating a PDF file from that text and facing issue with the created PDF (as shown in above screenshot text is getting cut in the Base report path).

Comment: As you can see that the samplePDF.pdf which is getting generated,text not displaying properly and is getting cut or hidden at the edge of pdf document.

Comment: Tilman, how should I use this setLandscape(true) in my above java code so that all the text would be visible in the new created PDF something like wordwrap feature should get enable while writing pdf file.

Comment: The PDFBox `TextToPDF` tool has no strategy to deal with single words which are longer than a line. Thus, these words are printed on a single line with their respective ends hidden after the page border. You may want to improve that tool to split such words at some appropriate position. The obvious issue to deal with is that upon re-extraction of the text (which you attempt with the `PDFTextStripper`), the word remains split.

Comment: @VarunJ The `TextToPDF` class has that method. Just call it before passing your text. Re "something like wordwrap feature should get enable while writing pdf file" we do wrap words but not within words. If you need this, either improve the tool or do a pre-processing of your input text.